# How to create a table using JSTL?

Tags: java, html, jstl, scriptlet

I have a String array. I want to create a table using the strings, their postion and a radio button for each row.
For example:

```
String a="abc&def&ghi&";
String b[]=a.split("&");
```

Using the string array `b[]` I want my page to display a table like this:

o --> radio button

```
--------------------
| num  | items     |
--------------------
| o 0  |  abc      |
--------------------
| o 1  |  def      |
--------------------
| o 2  |  ghi      |
--------------------
```

I tried using a `for` loop in a scriplet to generate the rows but if I do so, I cannot get the value of a particular radio button.

Can someone give me some idea on how to achieve this with JSTL or other methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want...

```
<%! int i = 0; %>
<c:forEach var="element" items="${string_array}">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio"  value="<%= i++ %>" name="item_radio">${element}   </td>    
    </tr>               
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: do not forget to add 

<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

at the top of the page